# Unknown Exception:AMF 15 while migrating from Flex 3.2 to Flex 4.6

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4, blazeds

I've spent last few days trying to migrate our application from flex 3.2 to flex 4.6. Although I've ironed out small issues, BlazeDs has been throwing an exception: 
[BlazeDS]Unknown AMF type '15'.

I suspect the problem could be with the serialization of the object from Java to Flex.

The exception trace is below.

```
[BlazeDS]Unknown AMF type '15'.
flex.messaging.io.UnknownTypeException: Unknown AMF type '15'.
at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Input.readObjectValue(Amf3Input.java:219)
at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Input.readObject(Amf3Input.java:132)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity; why are you moving to Flex 4.0?  Why not 4.6 (The last Adobe release) or 4.10 (the current Apache Release)?

Comment: I apologize. The migration is from Flex 3.2 to Flex 4.6. I have edited the post. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Maybe there are some libraries left in your build path coming from SDK 3.2? Just guessing, but maybe it helps, if you throw all the "fiber" stuff out and reconnect to your service (and thus reimporting all the libs from your current sdk). Maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a mismatch between the AMF versions you are using. AMF type 15 is only known in the AMF0 spec as XML object. The AMF3 spec does not contain a type 15 and XML is type 7.

Can you check if your remote objects are configured to use AMF3? You can set this via NetConnection.objectEncoding. The encodings are listed in the ObjectEncoding class.